# How can I pass properties into a Backbone.Model which I do not wish to be treated as attributes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone.Model named `Company`.
My `Company` model has an `Employees` Backbone.Collection containing `Employee` models.

When I instantiate my `Employee` models to populate the `Employees` collection I wish for them to have a reference to the `Company` they belong to.  But when I pass `Company` in it becomes one of the attributes of `Employee`.  This is an issue when I go to save the `Employee` because the `toJSON` method will contain a `Company` object, when in the database all I store is the foreign key integer `company_id`.

I wish there was a second parameter for Backbone.Model that accepted model properties that are not part of the core attributes.  How can I get around this?  I realize I could instantiate my `Employee` models and afterwards attach the `Company`, but I really want to do all the assignments in a traditional "constructor" rather than attach properties from outside.

e.g.:

```
Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({});

Employees = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Employee
});

Company = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.employees = new Employees({});
  }
});

c1 = new Company({id: 1});
e = new Employee({name: 'Joe', company_id: 1, company: c1});
c1.employees.add(e);

e.get('company'); // => c1

e.save(); // BAD -- attempts to save the 'company' attribute, when in reality I only want to save name and company_id


//I could do
c2 = new Company({id: 2});
e2 = new Employee({name: 'Jane', company_id: 2});
e2.company = c2;
c2.employees.add(e);

e.company; // => c2

//I don't like this second method because the company property is set externally and I'd have to know it was being set everywhere in the code since the Employee model does not have any way to guarantee it exists
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could always read it manually from the `options` object and store it however you like. The options are passed as the second argument to the initialize method:

```
var Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
        this.company = options.company;
    }
});
var shesek = new Employee({name: 'Nadav'}, {company: Foobar});
```

Alternatively, you can use [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) which makes it much easier to handle models that contains references to other models and collection.

You might also be interested in [making toJSON() recursive](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/483) (a patch I submitted to their issue tracker)

Comment: Backbone.Model shows it only accepts a single attributes array here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-constructor  I am tempted to try Backbone-relational but since Backbone itself is still changing I am afraid to invest in extensions that may not keep up with Backbone's rapid development.

Comment: But I see when looking in the code that Backbone.Model's initialize function does take both attributes and options.  My bad.

Comment: The docs are not updated. See the [constructor source](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L132)

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for. I will look at the code rather than just the documentation in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the save method on the model to convert the save record to only send name and company id.

```
Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({
   save: function() {
       var toSend = {name:this.get('name'),company_id: this.get('company').get('id')}
       // method to send toSend to server.
   }
});
```